# Angularfire 6 set default cloud functions region (location) for all functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, angularfire

How to **globally set default regions for firebase cloud functions** via angular fire so that they are **deployed** to specified region? Or it doesn't have to be with angular fire. I just don't want to call `.region('')` method with every function declaration.

I can't find anything in documentation about how to do it. But I've heard that it should be possible.
Previous versions of angular fire should support it.

Comment: Hello, I found [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations) official documentation in order to set Cloud Functions locations.

Comment: Yeah, but thats not for firebase and there is nothing about globally setting them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was blind. It is mentioned in angular fire documentation, under appropriate chapter name [Functions Region](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md)

in *app.module.ts*

```
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule, REGION } from '@angular/fire/functions';
...
...
    providers: [
      { provide: REGION, useValue: 'asia-northeast1' }
    ]
```

But that's not the right answer. I need them deployed to the correct region, and it didn't occurre to me that angular fire can't do that.

So if you don't want to set region at every function definition, you have to prefix(?) the definition with a global utility, so you do it only in one place.

in *functions-utils.ts*

```
import { region } from 'firebase-functions';

export class FunctionsUtils {

  public static get builder() {
    return region('desired-region-from-possible-options');
  }

}
```

and then use it in function declaration:
in *index.ts or whatever*

```
import { FunctionsUtils } from './functions-utils';

export const yourFunction = FunctionsUtils.builder.https.onCall(...
```

[List of available regions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations)

Comment: What's the most recent way to do it?, none of this seems possible. :/